# Connect to currently running hsqldb created from jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

How can I connect to a HSQLDB directly if it was started using jdbc?

I am starting an HSQLDB from JDBC as follows:

```
embeddedDb = new 
EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setName("sefs").setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8").addScript("classpath:schema.sql").build();
```

I then execute some code and stop execution on a breakpoint. I would now like to be able to connect to that database via some tool and directly execute some SQL-Statements for debuggging.

What tool can do this and how are the credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the database in embedded mode. Start an HSQLDB Server outside your application then connect to the server from your app. You can also connect with the HSQLDB DatabaseManager to perform debugging queries.